# Writing files with multibyte characters using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Good day, I have been going around the net for this but I am still at a loss..

```
fs.writeFile(PCAP_DIR + '赤さたな文字カナ.txt', '赤さたな文字カナ testing', {encoding: "utf8"}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Success');
    }
});
```

I tried the above code to write a file with japanese characters on the file name and the data. However, the output file results with the following filename:

```
�Ԃ����ȕ����J�i.txt
```

and inside is:

```
・ｽﾔゑｿｽ・ｽ・ｽ・ｽﾈ包ｿｽ・ｽ・ｽ・ｽJ・ｽi testing
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The code works fine, I was able to view it properly in Ubuntu, but not in Windows XP. So it has something to do with language support.

Comment: I also tried the code above in Windows 7 and Cent OS 6. It worked for Windows XP but not on Cent OS.